# ssh config to start session with google cloud compute instance using gcloud cli command

Tags: ssh, ssh-config, google-cloud

I would like to use my ssh config to use a google cloud cli (`gcloud`) to connect to google compute instances.  (This is a follow-on to another question I asked, that had a working solution, but didn't address this part of my question)

The desired functionality is `ssh <instance-name>.gc` would connect me to the gcloud instance.

To connect to the gcloud instance I can run:

```
/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@<instance-name>
```

So I added an entry to my .ssh/config:

```
Host *.gc
    ProxyCommand /home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@$(basename %h .gc)
```

I then run `ssh <instance-name>.gc` and get:

```
# ssh <instance-name>.gc
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
-bash: line 1: $'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0\r': command not found
```

It seems to establish a connection, but I don't have a prompt to type at, so I press ctrl-c to kill it.

I could make an alias to achieve similar behavior, but I want to be able to use it with other entries in my ssh config, so I can use it as a jumpbox.

---

### Debugging

It could be that I am misusing `ProxyCommand`, I get the same behavior if I replace the `gcloud` command with `ssh me@<instace-ip>` in the config file.  If this is the case, is there an alternative config that help me to achieve my goal?

`gcloud` uses `ssh` under the hood, you can pass arguments to ssh after adding a `--`. I have tried adding a `-- -t` to force pseudo-terminal allocation, without change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out some working syntax, maybe it could be cleaned up, but it works.

```
Host *.gc
    User me
    ProxyCommand gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@$(basename %h .gc) --command="nc 0.0.0.0 22"
```